# Is it possible to triple boot given the following partition state?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04

I have the following partitions on my drive:
[image]
I have researched online that it's not possible to have more than 4 primary partitions. I am not sure these are primary partitions, so will I be able to install windows as triple boot, I have Ubuntu and Kali dual booting as of now. If no, what can I do to be able to do so.

Comment: You are mixing up restrictions of legacy bios with uefi. See for instance http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Drive_Partition_Limits_Fact_Sheet.pdf   Usually the maximum number Linux kernel supports is 255.

Comment: When you install Windows make sure you backup your important Ubuntu and Kali files first.